# Is there an automated way to convert flow comment types to non commented types

Tags: flowtype

I have been using *flow comment types* for a while and would now like to get rid of the comments and use “real” type definitions.

I would for example like to convert

```
function upper(s/*: string*/)/*: string*/
```

to

```
function upper(s: string): string
```

and am looking for an automated way to do so?

Comment: Here's something doing the opposite: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-flow-comments/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're looking for exists, yet!

Based on ASTExplorer, [it looks like those comment types are parsed as if they are normal flow types](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/4010d268801977c1d70b1fadcdd56f86/780f63bcbdb5ef7bc5893ac5c7032a99a159c7ca):

```
const a /* : string */ = "blah"
```

Parses as:

```
"typeAnnotation": {
  "type": "TypeAnnotation",
  "loc": {
    "source": null,
    "start": {
      "line": 1,
      "column": 7
    },
    "end": {
      "line": 1,
      "column": 15
    }
  },
  "range": [
    7,
    15
  ],
  "typeAnnotation": {
    "type": "StringTypeAnnotation",
    "loc": {
      "source": null,
      "start": {
        "line": 1,
        "column": 9
      },
      "end": {
        "line": 1,
        "column": 15
      }
    },
    "range": [
      9,
      15
    ]
  }
},
```

So maybe if you just remove the node and add it back it will replace the comment annotation with a regular one? I'm just throwing stuff out here, but that's what I would do if I had a lot of replacement to do.

Alternatively, you could manually convert those over, but if the codebase is large enough (and your interest level is high enough), then manipulating the AST *might* be an interesting way to get this done.

Comment: Great idea! Would you know of example/template to start with for manipulating the AST?

Comment: I've got no experience in the area, but if I had to guess, it looks like you write some sort of `visitor` to manipulate matching nodes: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-flow-comments/src/index.js#L32

Comment: Here's the babel example/starter docs for writing a plugin: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook

Comment: Maybe try a replacement with `path.replaceWith(t.expression(node.expression));`? (based on https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-flow-comments/src/index.js#L38 )